# whenever try to run code it came up with this

Tags: c++, visual-studio, terminal

[Output in the terminal window when i run the code (pic of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhejH.jpg)Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"first program in vs studio";
   
    return 0;
}
```

when i tried to run this code it came up with:

{  cd "d:\vs" && g++ first.cpp -o first && "d:\vs"first

```
bash: cd: d:\vs" && g++ first.cpp -o first && d:vs"first: No such file or directory}
```

The above is processed by the IDE only.

Comment: How did you try to run the code? Are you showing us what you typed, by yourself, in the terminal window? Or are you showing something that was tried by an IDE? Or what, exactly? Anyway, if you are using Visual Studio on a Windows computer, why are you also using bash?

Comment: Your bash does not like backslashes. Use a forward slash instead. (I think you're confusing Visual Studio with the similarly named but completely unrelated Visual Studio Code.)

Comment: I am  using  vs code and in the terminal it is shown by by the IDE. Usually i used shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N to run the  code.

Comment: Anyone with this error just try to reinstall.]

Answer (score 2):

You have to write it as:

```
cd "d:\vs\" && g++ first.cpp -o first && "d:\vs\first"
```

You had a typo with your " that is misplaced. But since you are already inside your directory you might as well enter:

```
cd "d:\vs\" && g++ first.cpp -o first && first
```

Comment: Problems that are caused by a typo should not be answered; they should be closed with the reason "could not reproduce or caused by a typo" (under "community-specific").

Comment: This is true, but I mean that doesn't teach much does it?

Comment: how can the statement given by the IDE itself be a typo. I just write as it is in the terminal window.

Comment: Help me to solve this, otherwise kindly do not close the question.